# How to avoid adding duplicates in a many-to-many relationship table in SQLAlchemy - python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, duplicates, unique

I am dealing with a many-to-many relationship with sqlalchemy. My question is how to avoid adding duplicate pair values in a many-to-many relational table.

To make things clearer, I will use the example from the official SQLAlchemy documentation.

```
Base = declarative_base()

Parents2children = Table('parents2children', Base.metadata,                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Column('parents_id', Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id')),                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Column('children_id', Integer, ForeignKey('children.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_name = Column(String(45))
    child_rel = relationship("Child", secondary=Parents2children, backref= "parents_backref") 

    def __init__(self, parent_name=""):
        self.parent_name=parent_name
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<parents(id:'%i', parent_name:'%s')>" % (self.id, self.parent_name)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_name = Column(String(45))

    def __init__(self, child_name=""):
        self.child_name= child_name
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<experiments(id:'%i', child_name:'%s')>" % (self.id, self.child_name)

###########################################

def setUp():
    global Session
    engine=create_engine('mysql://root:root@localhost/db_name?charset=utf8', pool_recycle=3600,echo=False)
    Session=sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def add_data():
    session=Session()
    name_father1=Parent(parent_name="Richard")
    name_mother1=Parent(parent_name="Kate")
    name_daughter1=Child(child_name="Helen")
    name_son1=Child(child_name="John")

    session.add(name_father1)
    session.add(name_mother1)

    name_father1.child_rel.append(name_son1)
    name_daughter1.parents_backref.append(name_father1)
    name_son1.parents_backref.append(name_father1)

    session.commit()
    session.close()


setUp()
add_data()
session.close()
```

With this code, the data inserted  in the tables is the following:

*Parents table*:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | parent_name |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Richard     |
|  2 | Kate        |
+----+-------------+
```

*Children table*:

```
+----+------------+
| id | child_name |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Helen      |
|  2 | John       |
+----+------------+
```

*Parents2children table*

```
+------------+-------------+
| parents_id | children_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |           1 |
|          1 |           2 |
|          1 |           1 |
+------------+-------------+
```

As you can see, there's a duplicate in the last table... how could I prevent SQLAlchemy from adding these duplicates?

*I've tried to put* relationship("Child", secondary=..., **collection_class=set**) *but this error is displayed:*

```
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedSet' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: couldn't you check if a relationship already exists, before adding it again?

Answer (score 14):

Add a [PrimaryKeyConstraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#primary-key-constraint) (or a [UniqueConstraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint)) to your `relationship` table:

```
Parents2children = Table('parents2children', Base.metadata,                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Column('parents_id', Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id')),                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Column('children_id', Integer, ForeignKey('children.id')),
  PrimaryKeyConstraint('parents_id', 'children_id'),
)
```

and your code will generate an error when you try to commit the relationship added from both sides. This is very recommended to do.

In order to not even generate an error, just check first:

```
if not(name_father1 in name_son1.parents_backref):
    name_son1.parents_backref.append(name_father1)
```

Comment: that almost works :) but how could I prevent SQL Alchemy from adding same entries in "children" table for example??

Comment: What is the solution for "avoid adding same entries in "children" table?